# Can I disable OLE pasting from Photoshop to Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, adobe-photoshop, ole

When I copy an image from Photoshop into MSWord it defaults to creating an OLE object instead of a bitmap image. This is never what I want as it is harder to work with, and incredibly slow.
If I remember I can prevent this problem by using Paste Special, however no other program gives me this grief so I rarely remember until after I've caused Photoshop to freeze.

Can I change the defaults or disable OLE to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 0):

On a Microsoft Support page there is this statement about the Paste Special command and OLE objects:

"When you paste a bitmap using the Paste Special command, you have several options for how you paste the object from the Paste Special dialog box. If you select Bitmap or Picture (metafile), the presentation of the object is drawn by the client application, not the OLE libraries. The object is no longer an OLE object, it's a static object. A static object merely contains the bitmap or metafile format; all links to the object have been removed."

Therefore if you select Bitmap or Picture in Paste Special is Photoshop (the client application) that draws the image in Word and the image (the static object) is no more linked or embedded as an OLE object.

So, as you write in your question, you already know how to disable OLE pasting. You have just to remember to use Paste Special.

This is the page:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/88116/difference-between-bitmap-and-picture-when-using-paste-special

Comment: He did mention "paste special" already in his question.. So can you elaborate on how your solution is better? or different to what he is doing